# Can I switch 301 redirect direction from A->B to B->A and how does it affect SEO?

Tags: seo, domains, redirects, 301-redirect

I have a blog  that has been up for a few years. It doesn't contain a great number of pages but the domain name contains two keywords that I want to rank for, like `keyword1-keyword2.com`.

I have started a consultancy firm within my keyword areas (sustainability communications) and I want to market my company name but at the same time benefit from whatever authority my blog has gained for my keywords. I have understood that properly doing a 301 redirect will enable me to keep the domain authority and page ranking.

Question: Is it safe to switch redirect direction?

Regarding

1. page authority/rank in Google
2. technical feasibility

is there a problem switching direction of the 301 to one of the following

- `keyword1-keyword2.com`  -> `companyname.com`
- `keyword1-keyword2.com`  -> `companyname.com/keyword1-keyword2`

instead of

- `companyname.com`  ->  `companyname.keyword1-keyword2.com`

(which is how it is set up at the moment, with Wordpress MU domain mapping to make sure the address bar says `companyname.com`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From an SEO standpoint, moving from a keyword domain to a company branded domain is a good move.  The [2014 SearchMetrics Ranking Factors](http://www.searchmetrics.com/media/documents/knowledge-base/searchmetrics-ranking-factor-study__2014.pdf) found that that having keywords in the domain name is no longer a significant ranking factor.     I consider hyphens in domain names to be bad for rankings as well.   Moving to company branded domain name is a good move for you from and SEO perspective.

Keep in mind that anytime you do URL changes you may see fluctuations for a while.   You may even lose some rankings initially.   In the long term (months and years), you'll come out ahead.

From a technical perspective, the only problem is that 301 redirects are [highly cacheable](http://getluky.net/2010/12/14/301-redirects-cannot-be-undon/).   Any visitors that visited `companyname.com` recently, will have the 301 redirect from there cached by their browser.  They may have to manually clear their cache before browsing your website after you reverse the redirect.  I highly doubt that a large number of people would have visited the domain given that it wasn't much in use, so I suspect that it will only be an issue for a handful of people.   Maybe even just yourself.

Comment: Is the caching thing really an issue? If A is cached as a redirect then surely when a B->A redirect is encountered, browsers will check A again.